# Debugging a renamed DLL?

Tags: debugging, windbg, symbols

I am having problems trying to debug a DLL, which has been renamed during the post-build process: WinDBG fails to load the correct symbols (pdb file).
Example:
Original file name was: abc.dll
The created PDB is named: abc.pdb
During post-build process the DLL was renamed to 'a-b.DLL'.
For some reason when debugging I can see the module apears as 'a_b.dll' (hyphen was replaced by underscore, not sure why this happen). In addition, WinDBG cannot load its symbols.
I tried `ld a_b /f abc`, and also tried to rename PDB as 'a_b.pdb', and then called  `.reload /f /i a_b`, but also this did not work.
All this happens in my `Release` build, which was set to add debug-info and created PDB, as it does.

Comment: do `!sym noisy` before `.reload ...` and see what the debugger is trying to load and why it fail/does not find the correct pdb

Comment: When a module is compiled, debug details are embedded in the PE header. These details consist of a GUID that is shared between the module and the PDF and is used for matching symbols, as well as a path to the PDB file. You can view this with "dumpbin /headers <module>" and searching the Debug Directories output. Since the path in your DLL to the PDB symbols no longer matches, it is unable to load the symbols. Try !sym noisy to see if there are other options it tries to match/load the symbols.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the PDB is part of the DLL. Renaming the DLL will not change its contents, so renaming the PDB as well will not work. Instead, keep the original name.

Make sure your symbols are set up correctly, e.g. use Microsoft symbols and your own symbols:

```
.symfix c:\debug\symbols
.sympath+ c:\path_to\myproject\bin\Release
.reload
```

Also, don't worry about the module name in WinDbg. It replaces some special characters, but won't affect symbol loading. If you still have problems getting symbols laded, turn on symbol debug outout

```
!sym noisy
```

This should show the paths and file names where WinDbg tries to load symbols from. Check if your location is included. If not, add it via `.sympath+`. When done, turn symbols debugging off by

```
!sym quiet
```

This command is equivalent to

```
.symopt+ 0x80000000    *** noisy
.symopt- 0x80000000    *** quiet
```

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Apparently this was another one of them of 'rebuild-all and retry' cases. Sorry for the false alarm and thanks all for the answers.