# How can you load the symbols of a renamed executable that crashed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging

I've built a C++ program in C++ (e.g. app.exe). After compiling and linking I renamed the executable (e.g. app_v1.exe).

However, while running a special case my application crashed. The resulting dump file points to the renamed executable (i.e. app_v1.exe).

Visual studio does not allow me to use the debugging symbols of the original executable. Is there a change that I can do, e.g. edit the dump file so that I can use the debugging symbols of the original executable?

Comment: Depends if the executable was compiled in debug mode (with symbols) or in release mode (without symbols).  Also depends on whether the symbols were stripped using an external symbol remover utility.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the executable was compiled in debug mode with symbols. No stripping was done. The only change was renaming the executable after linking.

Comment: @fvanrysselberghe, If you change the exe/dll name, they will not match the previous PDB file. As far I know, it will impact the debugging, you could check the Debug Modules window to find useful information, you could also use the Windbg to find much more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648546/debugging-a-renamed-dll